# Get today's date, find it in table full of date's. MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL table full of date's in the format DATE. How would I find the current date, and then find it in the table and echo out its position in terms of `row_id`?

I understand I'm not providing any code with this question, but I'm struggling to find a place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function to match the current date:

```
select row_id from date_table where date_column = CURDATE();
```

Comment: $todaysday = date('Y,m,d');
 if ($currentDate == $todaysday) {
  echo "THIS IS TODAY";
 }

Comment: current date is a selection in a table is the syntax alright on this?